# Keep Me Signed In code in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, authentication, silverlight-4.0

Can anyone provide the code for "Keep me Signed In"(on Login Page) functionality in silverlight 4.0?

I have searched a lot but not getting any appropriate code.

Comment: See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/4d3fe14c-0bc5-4a23-879a-6e5ca29bc51f/remember-me-functionality-at-login

Comment: You mean Cookies? If the question is how to use cookies in Silverlight I can show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Cookies or IsolatedStorageSettings.
I have once used Cookies in my Silverlight Application.

```
private void SetCookie(string key, string value)
{
    DateTime expiration = DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromDays(2000);
    string cookie = String.Format("{0}={1};expires={2}", key, value, expiration.ToString("R"));
    HtmlPage.Document.SetProperty("cookie", cookie);
}

private string GetCookie(string key)
{
    string[] cookies = HtmlPage.Document.Cookies.Split(';');

    foreach (string cookie in cookies)
    {
        string[] keyValue = cookie.Split('=');

        if (keyValue.Length == 2 && keyValue[0].Trim() == key)
        {
            return HttpUtility.UrlDecode(keyValue[1]);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

So you can set cookies whenever you want and get them like that:

```
 SetCookie("WebUsername", UsernameTextBox.Text);
 SetCookie("WebPassword", PasswordtextBox.Text);

 UsernameTextBox.Text = GetCookie("WebUsername");
 PasswordBox.Password = GetCookie("WebPassword");
```